# Error program built with Flask and Python

Tags: python, flask

When I set the variables in the browser, it gives the error

```
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str
```

Code python:

```
@app.route('/UP_Pro' ,methods = ['GET'])
def MMD13():
    id = request.args.get('id') 
    Name = request.args.get('Name')
    tozih = request.args.get('tozih')
    Pol = request.args.get('Pol')
    aks = request.args.get('aks')    
    daste = request.args.get('daste')
    takh = request.args.get('takh')
    a=sqlite3.connect('Online_Shop.db')
    b=a.execute("UPDATE Products SET Products_Name ='"+Name+"',Description ='"+tozih+"',Price ='"+Pol+"',Image ='"+aks+"',Category_ID ="+daste+",Discount ='"+takh+"'WHERE Products_ID ="+id+"")
    a.commit()
    return id   

app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=5000)
```

I type this in the browser

```
http://192.168.1.33:5000/UP_Pro?id=2&Name=ram&tozih=ram-DDR4&Pol=200$&aks=ll&daste=2$takh=20%
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message "can only concatenate str (not 'NoneType') to str" indicates that one of the variables being concatenated is None, which means that it does not have a value. In this case, the error is likely caused by one or more of the arguments (id, Name, tozih, Pol, aks, daste, takh) not being passed in the request.

To fix the code, you can add some validation to ensure that all the required arguments are present in the request before trying to use them. Here's an updated version of the code with validation:

```
@app.route('/UP_Pro' ,methods = ['GET'])
def MMD13():
    id = request.args.get('id')
    if id is None:
        return "Error: missing 'id' parameter"
    
    Name = request.args.get('Name')
    if Name is None:
        return "Error: missing 'Name' parameter"
    
    tozih = request.args.get('tozih')
    if tozih is None:
        return "Error: missing 'tozih' parameter"
    
    Pol = request.args.get('Pol')
    if Pol is None:
        return "Error: missing 'Pol' parameter"
    
    aks = request.args.get('aks') 
    if aks is None:
        return "Error: missing 'aks' parameter"
    
    daste = request.args.get('daste')
    if daste is None:
        return "Error: missing 'daste' parameter"
    
    takh = request.args.get('takh')
    if takh is None:
        return "Error: missing 'takh' parameter"
    
    a=sqlite3.connect('Online_Shop.db')
    b=a.execute("UPDATE Products SET Products_Name ='"+Name+"',Description ='"+tozih+"',Price ='"+Pol+"',Image ='"+aks+"',Category_ID ="+daste+",Discount ='"+takh+"'WHERE Products_ID ="+id+"")
    a.commit()
    return id
```